# SOLR stats on distinct value

Tags: solr, aggregate-functions, bigdata, cloudera, distinct-values

Using SOLR, I have indexed device specific events. Each event containins a MAC address (deviceID) and a timestamp (ts). 
I would like to compute the distinct number of devices per day.
I have tried the following code based on the Stats component (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component). 
Since ts has this format "2014-09-01T00:00:00Z", the events will be grouped by second. I would like my events to be grouped by day.

SOLR Query:

```
.../solr/collectionVRtft_shard1_replica1/
query?q=":"
facet=true&
facet.field=ts
&facet.stat=stbCount:unique(deviceID)
```

Results:

```
"facet_counts": {
"facet_queries": {},
"facet_fields": {
"ts": [
"2014-10-09T12:11:11.782Z",
2,
"2000-01-01T00:01:15.827Z",
1,..
```

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: what if you add one more field "date" and group by that field instead?

Comment: It is a good idea but I cannot modify the events structure. I receive these events from an external source :)

Comment: you can use a copy field?

Comment: I am new in SOLR. You are talking about this option? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields

Comment: I think I could add a copy field. I need to truncate the ts field, right? Do you have an example of how I could truncate? RegEx?

Comment: Thanks! In the copy field I used a maxChars to truncate the timestamp. It work like a charm. Thanks for sharing!